# If $A\subset \lambda D$ then $\exists A'$ such $A=\lambda A'$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, domain-theory

Let be $D$ a commutative domain, $\lambda\in D\setminus \{0\}$ and $A\subset D$ an ideal. Then

> if $A\subset \lambda D$ then exists $A'\subset D$ such $A=\lambda A'$

**my work:**
If $A=\lambda D$ since $A$ is an ideal then $D$ is and ideal and is enough take $A'=D$. If $A\neq D$ then $\exists b\in D:\lambda b\notin A\rightarrow b\notin A$. If we take $B=\{b\in D: \lambda b \notin A\}$ then we have $A'=D\setminus B.$ am I right?

Any hint? Any recomended book for theory? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $A'$ is a little roundabout. It's more direct to define

$$A' = \{ x \in D : \lambda x \in A\}.$$

Now it remains to see that $A'$ has the required properties. We need to verify $A = \lambda A'$. By definition, we have $\lambda A' \subset A$. And since by assumption $A \subset \lambda D$, for every $a\in A$ there is a $d\in D$ with $a = \lambda d$. That implies $\lambda d \in A$, and hence $d \in A'$, so we also have $A \subset \lambda A'$.

Although it is not explicitly stated, I think that one is also expected to show that $A'$ is an ideal of $D$. That means one needs to verify

- $0 \in A'$,
- $x,y \in A' \implies (x-y) \in A'$,
- $x\in A',\, \mu \in D \implies \mu x \in A'$.

All these verifications are straightforward (the last, since $D$ is commutative).

Comment: excuse me, why $d\in A'$ implies $A\subset \lambda A'$ ?

Comment: We start from an arbitrary $a\in A$. By assumption, there is a $d\in D$ with $a = \lambda d$ (since $D$ is a domain, there is only one such $d$, but we don't need that here). By definition of $A'$, we have $d\in A'$, since $\lambda d \in A$. So we have shown $a \in \lambda A'$. But $a$ was arbitrary, in formulae $(\forall a \in A)(\exists d\in A')(a = \lambda d)$. And $(\exists d \in A')(a = \lambda d)$ is nothing but $(a \in \lambda A')$, so we have $(\forall a \in A)(a\in \lambda A')$. And that means $A\subset \lambda A'$.

Comment: Now is clear to me, thank you.